# JQuery/AJAX & PHP - Error with isset() when using .load() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I have a registration page on my website for which I want to implement PHP and AJAX validation. I will show template of my code (my code is much bigger) to try to explain the problem.

**registration.php**

```
<!DOCUMENT html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#signupForm").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var firstNameInput = $("#firstName").val();
     var lastNameInput = $("#firstName").val();
     $(".messageForm").load("inculdes/signup.script.php", {
      firstName: firstNameInput,
      lastName: lastNameInput
     });
    });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form id="signupForm" action="includes/signup.script.php" method="POST">
   <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName">
   <input id="firstName" type="text" name="firstName">
   <button id="submit" name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
   <div class="messageForm"></div>
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

**signup.script.php**

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   include "dbconn.script.php";

   $firstName = $_POST['firstName'];
   $lastName = $_POST['lastName'];

   //Validators for inputs in PHP with various error messages (1-15) and database INSERT and SELECT functions.
   ...

  } else {
     echo "<span>Error 16</span>";
     exit();
    }
  }
 ?>

 <script>
  // JQuery validator for inputs and CSS style changers based on errors
  ...
 </script>
```

My problem is when I click Submit button, I get error message "Error 16", so my function skip whole PHP script and does not insert data into database. I concluded that the problem is because the variable `$_POST['submit']` is not set, because when I change first line of code to `if (!isset($_POST[submit'']))`, it works like charm, but I don't wanna loose ability to prevent users from type `signup.script.php` in URL field of the browser and run it. How to correct this to work? The tutorial I watched has this code and in that case it works without problem.

P.S. I will expand my code if needed for solution of this problem, because I wanted to spare space so I gave the shorthand version of it.

Comment: Sorry, those are my typing errors now, I don't have them in my original code. I corrected them here.

Comment: you simply don't send `submit` with the request. You could add it here: `{
      firstName: firstNameInput,
      lastName: lastNameInput,
      submit: 1
     }` - _or_ check for `isset($_POST['firstName'])`

Comment: @MartinZeitler sure? `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object`

Comment: _"Sorry, those are my typing errors now"_ - Please don't rewrite the code for SO. Do a real copy/paste of your actual code.

Comment: you also have 2 id's of the same name and of the same name attribute. ID's are unique - Edit: As @MagnusEriksson said; post the real code here. Check your developer console and use php's error reporting. Viewing HTML source and `var_dump()` are additional debugging tools.

Comment: `inculdes` is that also just a typo? The word is spelled "includes".

Comment: ^ ...and this is why you need to post the _actual_ code, so we don't sit and debug errors that don't really exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply don't send "submit" with the request. 
You could add it here:

```
$(".messageForm").load("inculdes/signup.script.php", { 
   firstName: firstNameInput, 
   lastName: lastNameInput, 
   submit: 1 
});
```

or check for `isset($_POST['firstName'])`

*Sidenote:* If there wasn't an object passed in with `load()` it would be a GET request. Worth remembering...

> *Request Method*
>
> The POST method is used if data is provided as an object; otherwise, GET is assumed.

[The Docs](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Comment: So check your console/network log in your browser. The moment you hit submit, is it a GET or POST request?

Comment: better check the OP's code again there Jeff, as per a few comments I left under their post.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner Yes, I know there are more issues, which could be only typos from transferring code. We don't know. The one issue I pointed out seemed to be the critical non-typo one.

Comment: @Jeff The guy made edits at the beginning where I pointed out their typos which they fixed after and I deleted my comments. It's hard to say where we're to throw ourselves here LOL!

Comment: Thank you for the help! Adding `submit` at the end of `load()` function make it work like a charm! If I only asked earlier I wouldn't spent 30 hours looking for solution.

Answer (score 0):

according to the jQuery documentation of [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) (which is a shorthanded `jQuery.ajax` method), this sound much alike if this would be a `$_GET` and not a `$_POST`... better use something alike [jQuery.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) in combination with `method: 'POST'` - or check for the `$_GET` in PHP.

Comment: from the docs: `The POST method is used if data is provided as an object`

Comment: @Jeff indeed, the absent field `submit` might be the culprit then.

Answer (score 0):

Dear check your JavaScript code carefully

```
event.preventDefault(); // Preventing default form submission

$(".messageForm").load("inculdes/signup.script.php", {
      firstName: firstNameInput,
      lastName: lastNameInput
});
```

Only posts firstName and lastName to signup.script.php

And you are trying to check for `isset($_POST['submit'])` 
It will surely be false until you pass 'submit' in post like firstName and lastName you have passed already like below

```
$(".messageForm").load("inculdes/signup.script.php", {
      firstName: firstNameInput,
      lastName: lastNameInput,
      submit: 'yes'
});
```

Hope it helps

Comment: This is the solution. Thank you very much.